# align mobile button to the right is not working

Tags: css

How to align the mobile btn to the right? Im using justify-content-between in the row div but its not working.

```css
header {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div class="col">
                <h1 class=" Header__logo">Logo</h1></div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="Header__mobile">
                    <a href="" class="Header__mobile_btn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <ul class="Header__mobile_list d-none">
                        <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
                      
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flex property is only visibly affecting direct children of your row. Try putting your button as a direct child of the row.